# Google script -- adding days to a date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I realize this is likely very easy but I'm a struggling newbie.  I have dates in spreadsheet cells D3, D4, and D5 (mm/dd/yyyy) and simply need a macro to add 7 days to each of them.  I've managed to mangle together some code that may be working but the output is in milliseconds rather than mm/dd/yyyy format.

I can't seem to get the syntax right to convert it. Any hints?  Thank you!

```
function UpdateDates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var First = new Date();
  var Second = new Date();
  var Third = new Date();

  var First = ss.getRange('D3').getValue();
  var Second = ss.getRange('D4').getValue();
  var Third = ss.getRange('D5').getValue();


  ss.getRange('D3').setValue(First.getTime() + 7);
  ss.getRange('D4').setValue(Second.getTime() + 7);
  ss.getRange('D5').setValue(Third.getTime() + 7);

}
```

Comment: I realize now that part of the issue (among others) is that I used getTime rather than getDate.  After that change, the format is good but the dates are nowhere near accurate.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Adding days to date provides a unique challenge mainly because you have to take care of year, month and date. And increment each accordingly, hence just using [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) doesn't work. You will need to keep track of the month and year. So as to change them if adding the seven days change the month or the year.

However, by using [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) you can get the measure of time in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. And, add 7 days in milliseconds and convert it back to a date using [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype) constructor. Thus the constructor would take of figuring out the correct date based on the time.

Your code will look like so:

```
function UpdateDates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Get the dates from the cell and convert them into Milliseconds since 1970/01/01
  var First = new Date(ss.getRange('D3').getValue()).getTime();
  var Second = new Date(ss.getRange('D4').getValue()).getTime()
  var Third = new Date(ss.getRange('D5').getValue()).getTime();
  var dayInMs = 24*60*60*1000    //one day in Milliseconds
  //add sevendays to each date in milliseconds

  First = First + (7*dayInMs)
  Second += (7*dayInMs)
  Third += (7*dayInMs)

  //Convert Milliseconds to date use new Date(time in ms) and set Values of the cell
  ss.getRange('D3').setValue(new Date(First));
  ss.getRange('D4').setValue(new Date(Second));
  ss.getRange('D5').setValue(new Date(Third));

}
```

Comment: Jack -- thank you so much!  It all makes sense logically.  I was struggling so much with the syntax but can use this as a good starting point for future needs.   I had become "dangerous" with Excel VBA but was having a hard time moving to Google Script.  Thanks again!